# Pattern confirmation consumer / producer without autostart of kafkalistener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

to achieve to start a spring boot application without a needed running kafka server I defined the consumer with autostartup=false in this way:

```
 @KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = {"myTopic"}, autoStartup = "false")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, Foo> consumerRecord) {
        log.info("consuming {}", consumerRecord);
    }
```

Now to start initially the consumer I tied it to the producer of this topic in the producer in this way:

```
public void sendFoo(Foo foo) {

        try {
            kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myContainer").start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.info(e.getMessage());
        }
        kafka.send(mytopic, foo);
    }
```

Is this the recommended pattern or does a better one exist ?

Comment: what's wrong in this, i don't see anything wrong

Comment: The question is if this is okay or there exist a better approach.

Comment: first what is your requirement

Comment: The requirement is to start an spring application with a consumer / producer for kafka that starts without a running kafka server. Without the tag autoStartup=false the Spring application would not start unless a kafka server is running. Everything works. The point is that the listener has to be activated and my question is if to trigger this when a message is produced is the right pattern or not. The questions is not about if it works - because it works - but if this is the most convienent solution to achieve the goal to start a Spirng application without running kafka server.